# Git: working after pull request from master branch

Tags: git, branch, pull, git-fork

I made a mistake. I created a pull request that's currently in review from my fork from `master` branch. Review can take up to several weeks (public open source project) and I want to work on other feature for which I would like to create separate pull request. Now when I create a new branch it is based on my master branch and has changes from the first pull request so they will go with the new pull request (I guess). How I can recover from that situation?

I've started working with git just a several weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to run git command : git reset --hard "SHA-1 of the previous state". 
It will bring you git code to the state prior to git pull.

you can find  "SHA-1 of the previous state" by running command : git-reflog

Then just create new branch from that state and work on new feature in new branch.

Comment: Be careful with `git reset --hard` since it might throw away uncommitted changes which can't be restored (use `git stash` for them - ideally after reading `man git stash`).

Comment: Yes, Please take "git stash" if you have made any changes after taking pull from master.

Comment: Ok, I'll remember that. Thanks a lot for your answer. Have a good day.